# Как работает возврат ссылки?

Tags: c++

Что-то я туплю...
Есть класс буфера, который, возвращая элемент, копирует его в свой член OutObject и возвращает ссылку на OutObject. Принимается же этот элемент в объект:

```
struct DataStr;

DataStr& TBuffer::get( void )
{
// ...
OutObject = *OldElement;
return OutObject;
}

DataStr data;
data = buffer->get();
```

К какой области памяти теперь относится data? К той же, что и раньше? Или к OutObject? Или здесь все же происходит копирование значения?

Comment: - При выполнении метода `get` для `OutObject` будет вызван деструктор и `operator=(*OldElement)`, определенный явно или неявно.

- После выполнения этого кода для `data` будет вызван оператор присваивания с параметром-ссылкой на результат метода `get`.

Comment: Не понял, какой еще деструктор?
Получается, ссылку возвращать бесполезно? Можно просто объект?

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать поясни пожалуйста когда вызовется конструктор data ?
в **DataStr data;** или **data=...** а то твой пост меня слегка путает :)

Comment: Чтобы не вызывался деструктор, надо немного поправить код. 
DataStr &data = buffer->get(); 
В этом случае никаких лишних вызовов не будет.
Однако при этом надо следить, чтобы возвращаемая по ссылке переменная не была уничтожена.

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat В строчке `DataStr data;` будет вызван конструктор для без параметров `DataStr::DataStr()`. В том случае, если этот вызов можно доказуемо соптимизировать, то, наверно, этого вызова не произойдет, но потенциально он имеет место быть.

@cyrax Вообще, метод какой-то странный и путающий. Неконстантный `getter,` который содержит какую-то логику - это всегда плохо. Не думайте о количестве копирований (поскольку есть `RVO` и прочие полезные штуки), лучше задумайтесь о том, как сделать метод `get` константным и прозрачным. Возвращать объект можно и по значению.

Comment: Забыл, кстати, сказать, что для `data` будет вызван конструктор по умолчанию, **деструктор,** а только после этого - `operator=(const T&)`

Comment: до меня не дошло:(

    1.DataStr data;//тут конструктор по умолчанию
    2.data = buffer->get();//тут оператор присваивания

а где(строчка?) когда (до, после чего?) будет вызван деструктор data??

Comment: Объясните, чем плох неконстантный getter? Это буфер на шаблонах, и возвращать произвольные объекты вместо ссылок может быть весьма накладно (хотя здесь эти преимущества и не  используются). С деструктором я так же не понял, мы вообще про с++ говорим? Приведите пожалуйста ссылку на стандарт или статью, где это подтверждается.

Comment: @cyrax, почитайте лучше [вот это](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/).

А потом задумайтесь, что можно делать в крестах, а от чего, если не припрет  (например, исправление **чужого кода**) надо держаться подальше.

Comment: Я лично так и не понял какого типа переменные `OutObject` и `OldElement`. Без этого дальнейший разговор бессмысленен.

Comment: А с кем это вы так разговаривали? Говнокод это потому, что вы не поняли типа этих двух членов или еще по каким-соображениям? Оба этих члена именно того типа,которому присваивается результат  get - DataStr.

Comment: @cyrax, Вы на самом деле чего хотите?

Хранить данные в памяти экземпляра объекта и обращаться к этой памяти?

Тогда так и код напишите. Возвращайте указатель на эти байты и не морочьте (прежде всего себе самому) голову.

Если хотите копировать, тогда явно (например, вызвав memcpy()) копируйте.

Делайте просто и понятно. Про KISS принцип слышали?

Comment: @cyrax, это совершенно неочевидно.Может у Вас там преобразования какие-либо сделаны.Как-то все очень неявно.И вопросы детские.
Чтобы ликвидировать неясности нужно сделать отладочный вывод в перегруженных оператор, в частности, **=**, и самому посмотреть, что происходит.Мое мнение таково:

> К какой области памяти теперь относится data? К той же, что и раньше?

data относится к старой области памяти, но содержимое членов класса будет переписано полученным из буфера.Как следствие-запросто можете получить геморрой с выделением памяти,т.к. объект, возвращаемый из `buffer->get()`,должен грохнуться

Comment: Какой геморрой? DataStr обычная структура без указателей. Если значение из  OutObject туда просто копируется, то где вы нашли выделение памяти? Надо было конечно весь код привести, но так как вопрос простейший, не стал этого делать... Пока что похоже, вы просто не разобрались в коде, но пытаетесь отвечать и даже высказываете мнения.

Comment: @cyrax, ну, так и привели бы весь код. В чем проблема?
Касательно геморроя - это если внутри DataStr есть указатели. ОК. Указателей там нет. Тогда соглашусь с @avp - а чего тогда `memcpy` не воспользоваться? TBuffer - Ваш код? Или библиотечный? Его есть возможность поменять?

У меня вообще возникает соблазн поменять сигнатуру buffer->get(), чтобы возвращался константный указатель на DataStr...

Answer (score 15):

о боже, ответ получился безумно длинным  и без BBcode выглядит ужасно нечитабельно :((

не пугайтесь огромного размера :))

---

---

---

## предисловие

```
чтобы не было путаницы ввиду пару обозначений
$ //некое место в коде (может иметь номер $1,$2)

переменная //именованная область данных (переменная с именем)
^ // временная переменная без имени но с адресом в памяти

адрес_объекта //адрес в памяти какого-нибудь объекта
адрес_переменной //адрес какой то переменной

переменная_указатель //переменная типа указатель
переменная_ссылка //переменная типа ссылка
переменная_объект //переменная типа объект

int переменная_объект    //переменная типа int
int переменная_указатель //указатель на int 
int переменная_ссылка    //ссылка на int

(текст) //какие то мысли или пояснение
```

---

---

---

## что такое ссылка ?

все ссылки это по сути константные указатели (не путать с указателем на конст)

то есть

```
тип * const имя_переменной_указатель
```

у ссылок есть пара отличий от просто указателя

1. нельзя менять адрес_объекта
2. адрес_объекта не может быть равным
       нулю
3. тип ссылки и объекта должен быть
       одинаковым
4. адрес_объекта можно назначить только
       во время создания ссылки

во время компиляции, компилятор автоматически переделает ссылку в **`конст_переменная_указатель`**, возьмёт **`адрес_объекта`** и во всех местах где используется ссылка подставит разыменование (**`*`**`конст_переменная_указатель`)...

---

---

---

## передача\возврат значений в\из функцию

главное всегда помнить в функцию ничего не передаётся и функция ничего не возвращает

на самом деле вы создаёте в **`функции`** новую переменную и присваиваете ей значение из **`вызвавшей_функции`** (эта переменная может быть указателем, ссылкой или объектом)

при возврате вы создаёте в **`вызвавшей_функции`** новую переменную и присваиваете ей значение из **`функции`** (эта переменная так же может быть указателем, ссылкой или объектом. Она имеет адрес в памяти но не имеет имени)

---

---

---

### создаём в **`функции`** новые переменные

##### ---------------пример1:

```
void fun(тип переменная_1_объект) $ {   
   \\...
}
\\--------------------------------\\
fun(переменная_объект);
```

при вызове **fun()** в месте **$** будет выполнена операция

```
тип переменная_1_объект = переменная_объект
```

---

##### ---------------пример2:

```
void fun(тип &переменная_1_ссылка) $ {   
   \\...
}
\\--------------------------------\\
fun(переменная_объект);
```

при вызове **fun()** в месте **$** будет выполнена операция

```
тип &переменная_1_ссылка = переменная_объект
```

---

##### ---------------пример3: (работать не будет)

```
void fun(тип *переменная_1_указатель) $ {   
   \\...
}
\\--------------------------------\\
fun(переменная_объект);
```

при вызове **fun()** в месте **$** будет выполнена операция

```
тип *переменная_1_указатель = переменная_объект //вот тут то и неработает
```

---

---

---

### создаём в **`вызвавшей_функции`** переменные без имени **"^"**

##### ---------------пример1:

```
тип fun(){   
   \\...
   return переменная_1_объект;
}
\\--------------------------------\\
$ fun();
```

в **`вызвавшей_функции`** в месте **$** будет выполнена операция

```
тип ^_объект = переменная_1_объект
```

---

##### ---------------пример2:

```
тип& fun(){   
   \\...
   return переменная_1_объект;
}
\\--------------------------------\\
$ fun();
```

в **`вызвавшей_функции`** в месте **$** будет выполнена операция

```
тип &^_ссылка = переменная_1_объект
```

---

##### ---------------пример3: (работать не будет)

```
тип* fun(){   
   \\...
   return переменная_1_объект;
}
\\--------------------------------\\
$ fun();
```

в **`вызвавшей_функции`** в месте **$** будет выполнена операция

```
тип *^_указатель= переменная_1_объект //вот тут то и неработает
```

---

---

---

### смешиваем

##### ---------------пример:

```
тип& fun(тип &переменная_1_ссылка)$1{   
   \\...
   return переменная_1_ссылка;
}
\\--------------------------------\\
$2 fun(переменная_объект);
```

в **`функции_fun`** в месте **$1** будет выполнена операция

```
тип &переменная_1_ссылка = переменная_объект
```

затем в **`вызвавшей_функции`** в месте **`$2`** будет выполнена операция

```
тип &^_ссылка = (переменная_1_ссылка)
```

тоесть **`^_ссылка`** и **`переменная_1_ссылка`** будут указывать на **`переменная_объект`**

---

**если кто не понял  привожу аналогичный код в виде указателей**

в **`функции_fun`** в месте **$1** будет выполнена операция

```
тип * const переменная_1 = &переменная //(объект)
```

затем в **`вызвавшей_функции`** в месте **`$2`** будет выполнена операция

```
тип * const ^ = &(*переменная_1) //
```

---

---

---

p.s стоит ли писать про то когда вызывается **`конструктор_копирования`**, а когда **`оператор=`** ???

p.s.s вопросы, недочёты, ошибки и т.д. писать в коментах под этим постом

p.s.s.s пусть "очень много "пожеланий"" создателей Markdown

Comment: Спасибо, очень полезный пост, часто подача материала поверхностная и это очень вреди понимаю, если поверхностный пример усложнить, по крайней мере так было в моем случае. А есть ли у вас ещё описание таких тонкостей? Или может книга какая с такой подачей информации без воды и лжи, а то сам уже не раз сталкивался с этим на других примерах.

Comment: @mzarb  нет к сожалению информацию пришлось собирать самому...
как говорится всё познаётся на ошибках :(

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat, ясно, буду тогда время от времени читать ваши ответы на другие вопросы и может наткнусь на что-то подобное:).

Comment: @mzarb ну я сам только учусь программировать, так что пока в голове больше бардака чем истины ;(