# Сколько есть способов передачи аргументов в функцию?

Tags: c, c++

Как по мне, то в С есть передача аргументов в функцию только по значению, а в С++ по факту тоже только передача по значению. То есть, передачи по указателю не может быть, потому что указатель содержит адрес, а это тоже значение. Так что правильней говорить, что передача по значению. Ну а насчет ссылок, то это те же указатели с константным адресом и которые неявно преобразуются к указателю, так что тоже передача по значению.
То есть, есть только передача по значению. А когда говорят о передаче по указателю и ссылке, то это скорей для того, чтобы внести ясность о том, будет ли переменная копирована или взят её адрес или так же неявно взят адрес с невозможностью заменить его на другой адрес.

В общем, условно(для упрощения понимания) есть 2 способа передачи аргументов в функцию в Си :
по значению,
по указателю.

И 3 способа в C++:
по значению,
по указателю,
по ссылке.

А по факту везде передается по значению и только.
В тесте по Си были 2 ответа : по значению, и по указателю. Но вопрос там был другой "Какими способами можно передавать параметры в функцию?". То есть, не аргументы, а параметры. Не совсем понимаю этот момент, но если предположить, что аргументы передаются в параметры, а потом параметры в тело функции, то параметры вполне могут передаваться по значению или указателю или по ссылке( в C++). И будет выглядеть как -

```
void func1 ( int   arg );
void func2 ( int * arg );
void func3 ( int & arg );
```

Из кода видно, что сами параметры могут быть и ссылкой и указателем, но тем не менее во всех трех случаях инициализированы они будут аргументами, которые передаются только по значению. 
Что-то мне кажется, что скорей всего не правильно был сформулирован вопрос теста и параметры не передаются в функцию, так как они и так в её сигнатуре, а передаются аргументы, ну а параметры просто инициализируются где-то между сигнатурой и телом в области видимости под которую попадает тело функции.

Comment: @strol, а все-таки вопрос-то в чем?

Вас интересует, как это происходит *на самом деле* (машинные команды) или с *точки зрения языка*?

--

Если кратко, то *на самом деле* все передается по значению. 

В 32-бит x86 архитектуре через копирование данных в 32-битные слова в стеке. В 64-бит несколько первых параметров копируются в 64-бит регистры, а остальные в стек.

--

А с т.з. языка -- в Си по *значению* (**передается копия**) и *указателю* (**речь о массивах!**), а в С++ еще и по *ссылке* (**это определяется видом аргумента в вызываемой функции**).

Comment: @avp, вот если с т.з. Си, разве в указателе хранится не значение? Которое потом присвоится параметру функции. Почему тогда нельзя сказать, что аргументы передаются в функцию только по значению с точки зрения языка?

Comment: @strol, IMHO Вы немного путаете указатель (переменная, значением которой является адрес) и непосредственно адрес.

Смотрите:

    int a[10], *p = &a[0]; // а можем написать p = a; (те же яйца, вид сбоку)

    foo(a[0]);   // передаем  "по значению"
    pfoo(p);     // передаем p "по значению", а значением является адрес a[0]
    pfoo(a);     // а вот это однозначно передача "по адресу". Мы пишем имя переменной, а компилятор передаст адрес ее первого байта, тот же адрес, что и в p
    pfoo(&a[0]); // думаю, это тоже называют "по адресу"

И обычно все друг друга понимают.

Comment: @avp, 
>pfoo(a);     // а вот это однозначно передача "по адресу". Мы пишем имя переменной, а компилятор передаст адрес ее первого байта, тот же адрес, что и в p
Если массивы - это синтаксический сахар и на самом деле имя массива - это указатель на его первый элемент, который содержит значение в виде адреса этого первого элемента, а к примеру параметр `array` функции `int pfoo (int * array)` получает аргумент `a` вызовом `pfoo(a);`, и условно передача выглядит как `int * array = a;`. То почему нельзя сказать, что передается по адресу, а не по значению? ...

Comment: ...Ведь в `int * array` запишется именно адрес первого элемента, который содержится как значение в указателе `a`. Вот в этом и суть вопроса. Что это должно быть вернее, а все остальное это дополнительные обозначения для лучшего понимания.

Comment: Если успели прочитать "что передается по адресу, а не по значению", то это случайно написал. Исправил на "что передается по значению, а не по указателю"

Comment: @strol: массивы — это не совсем синтаксический сахар. Например, для кода

    char array[100];
    char *p = array;
    size_t s1 = sizeof array;
    size_t s2 = sizeof p;

значение `s1` будет 100, а `s2` 4, 8 или сколько там размер указателя для текущей архитектуры.

Но в аргументах функций массивы и указатели — одно и то же.

Comment: @strol, это выражение 

    массивы - это синтаксический сахар и на самом деле имя массива - это указатель на его первый элемент, который содержит значение в виде адреса этого первого элемента

справедливо только в контексте аргументов функции. Вообще-то массив (в той области видимости, где под него память выделяется) это абсолютная реальность. Это последовательно размещенные в памяти однотипные переменные. И одинаково обращаться там с массивом и указателем не всегда можно. 

    foo(int a[], int *pa) {
       int b[10], *pb;

       a = 0; pa = 0; pb = 0; // можно
       b = 0; // нельзя

..

Comment: Вообще, по-моему наиболее простой ответ на вопрос:

      "Какими способами можно передавать параметры в функцию?"

Ответ д.б. -- в стеке или в регистрах.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, в C ровно один способ передачи аргументов: по значению. Передаёте ли вы по значению число или указатель, вы получаете с той стороны *копию* этого числа/указателя: если вы меняете число внутри функции, с его «внешним прообразом» (который может, кстати, быть и выражением) ничего не случается; если внешний прообраз меняется в течение выполнения функции, на значении аргумента это никак не отражается.

Иногда говорят, что передавая указатель на объект в функцию, вы как бы тем самым неявно передаёте сам объект в функцию «по указателю». Это на самом деле не вполне верный подход.

Давайте я приведу пример: представьте себе, что вам передали число. Вы использовали это число как индекс в глобальном массиве, и изменили элемент этого массива. Можно ли сказать, что вам был передан этот элемент? Нет, вы получили лишь число.

Точно так же можно смотреть на указатель как на индекс в памяти, рассматриваемой как массив байт. Доступ к объекту через указатель ничем не лучше и не хуже доступа к ячейке массива по индексу.

---

В C++ появился новый вид передачи параметров: по ссылке. По существу, передача «по ссылке» ничем не отличается от передачи указателя кроме того, что (1) ссылка не может соответствовать NULL-указателю в корректной программе, (2) ссылка синтаксически ведёт себя как разыменованный указатель.

Однако, разработчики C++ советуют всё же видеть в передачу по ссылке другую семантику: ссылка является «алиасом», другими именем объекта. Хотя такая семантика и более привлекательна с точки зрения ясности программ, всё же ссылка на объект и сам объект — не одно и то же. В частности, ссылка может пережить объект, и вы получите при попытке обратиться к ней undefined behaviour. Если бы ссылка *была* самим объектом (как это часто пытаются подать), такого произойти бы не смогло.

Следовать ли совету разработчиков или думать о передаче по ссылке как о синтаксическом сахаре для передачи по указателю — личное дело каждого. Я бы всё же советовал думать так, как советуют разработчики, но не упускать из виду, что эта абстракция «протекает».

---

ЗЫ: Пример кода без явных ошибок (наподобие возврата ссылки на локальную переменную), в котором ссылка на объект переживает сам объект:

```
class X
{
    struct C { int x; };
    C* pc;

    void f(int& x) { g(); cout << x << endl; }
    void g() { delete pc; }

public:
    X() : pc(new C()) {}
    void run() { f(pc->x); }
};
```

Comment: Не совсем понял ваше мнение. Вы тоже за то, что есть только 1 способ передачи аргументов и в Си и в С++? Мне это видится так: можно по разному называть опираясь на разные моменты передачи, но вот по факту от аргумента к параметру передается только значение, а не к примеру называть передачей по указателю, только потому, что указатель в аргументе вызова функции, ведь все ровно параметру будет присвоено содержимое указателя - адрес(значение). Если в вызове функции написан аргумент в виде функции, которая вернет указатель, то не называть же это передачей по функцие?

Comment: В общем, давая названия этому процессу передачи, видимо кто-то смотрит на сам указатель в аргументе, а не то, что этот указатель содержит, и по этому называет передачей по указателю. А кто-то может быть даже смотрит на принимающий указатель в параметре, и по этому тоже называет передачей по указателю. И в какой-то мере они правы, но цель вопроса была в том, что почему будет неправильным ответом сказать, что аргумент передается только по значению и в Си и в С++, если хоть тресни, но в параметр не попадет ничего, кроме значения из аргумента, и не важно будет аргумент указателем или нет.

Comment: Если кратко суммировать, я считаю, что в C один способ передачи параметров (по значению), а в C++ — полтора (по значению и по ссылке, которая есть по существу передача указателя по значению).

Представьте себе, что вам передан указатель на указатель на указатель на указатель на `int` — вы _можете_ по этой информации достучаться до исходного `int`'а, но вы ж не считаете это отдельным способом передачи параметров? В любом случае, в функцию поступает **значение** указателя (или указателя на указатель, или ...).

Comment: Вот ещё [код][1], так же ломает привязку к мнению, что аргумент передается по указателю. Потому как это должно было бы называться по значению, но так как аргумент можно модифицировать внутри функции, то нужно было бы назвать по указателю, но здесь же явно значение передается, если исходить из того, что есть 3 способа передачи. Так что можно называть это передачей по указателю, но если ставят вопрос as is о том, сколько есть способов передачи аргументов в функцию, то как по мне правильным ответом будет только по значению.


  [1]: http://ideone.com/IePELU

Answer (score 2):

при передачи по значению передаваемое значение не меняется, а внутри функции создается временная переменная.

при передачи по указателю или ссылки передается только адрес, передаваемый объект можно изменить изнутри функции и не создается локальной (временной) переменной внутри функции. разница между передачи ссылкой и указателем в удобстве употребления (не надо писать звездочку каждый раз внутри функции).

ниже пример:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void f_value(int a){ // значение
    a = 10; // изменяем параметр
}

void f_poiner(int * a){ // указатель
    *a = 10; // изменяем параметр
}

void f_reference(int & a){ // ссылка
    a = 20; // изменяем параметр
}

int main(){
    int a = 0;  
    cout << "a = " << a << endl;    
    f_value(a); // значение переменной (а) НЕ изменится после выполнения
    cout << "a = " << a << endl;    
    f_poiner(&a); // значение переменной (а) изменится после выполнения 
    cout << "a = " << a << endl;
    f_reference(a); // значение переменной (а) изменится после выполнения
    cout << "a = " << a << endl;

    return 0;
}

---------------------------------------------------

a = 0
a = 0
a = 10
a = 20
Press <RETURN> to close this window...
```

Comment: Это ясно. Но вопрос был в том, что эти понятия следствия передачи по значению спутались с тем, что происходит на самом деле или поставлен некорректно вопрос. Потому как аргумент передается в параметр всегда по значению, а дальше уже называют по разному в зависимости от того, что передалось, значение объекта или адрес, который тоже значение, только указателя.

Comment: на самом деле есть два способа передачи информации прямой и косвенный.
прямой - изменение значения непосредственного объекта
косвенный - изменения значения через некий дополнительный объект (в нашем случае ссылка или указатель)

если любишь терминологию то я еще добавлю что параметр еще на иногда называют аргументом )

Comment: @perfect, Вы пишете

    разница между передачи ссылкой и указателем в удобстве употребления (не надо писать звездочку каждый раз внутри функции).

на самом деле от передачи по ссылке (не автору кода, да и ему через пару месяцев после написания кода  тоже) приносит больше мороки, чем удобства.

При чтении такого кода все время приходится смотреть прототипы функций, чтобы представлять может параметр быть изменен в той или иной функции или нет.

IMHO наряду с возможностью переопределять операции это одна из самых неудачных "фич" в крестах.

Comment: @avp, там комментарии закончились, 
>это выражение
Насчет этого не совсем понял.
`int * array = a;`(напомню что это присваивание условно находится где-то перед телом функции) - это выражение? Тогда `int * array = a[0]);` ничем не отличается, так как в обоих случаях присваивается значение правого операнда, даже если этот правый операнд тоже выражение, то есть a или a[0], то все ровно они вернут значение. Так где же тут указатель? Может мы все-таки по разному интерпретируем слово значение? Для меня значение - это и содержимое a[0](какие-то цифры) и содержимое a(адрес).

Comment: @avp в чем то я согласен с вами

но ведь ссылка не позволяет выделить новую память под существующий объект, это все же короче чем,

    const тип * имя

Comment: @avp

да и к тому же есть стили написания имен ничто не мешает начинать имена таких переменных с буквы r

Comment: @perfect, я имел в виду вот что, в таком коде

    f1 (int &i) { i = 10; }
    g1 () { int i = 0; f1(i); cout << i; }

и

    f2 (int *i) { *i = 10; }
    g2 () { int i = 0; f2(&i); cout << i; }

в паре f2(),g2() буковок, конечно, больше, чем в f1(),g1(), но что происходит в f2(),g2() **значительно очевидней** (особенно когда речь идет о десятках тысяч строк в полусотне файлов, размещенных в нескольких каталогах).

--

А вот что означает фраза

    но ведь ссылка не позволяет выделить новую память под существующий объект

я, если откровенно, не понял.

Comment: @strol, теперь я Вас похоже уже не понимаю.

Вы пишете

     int * array = a;..... Тогда int * array = a[0]); ничем не отличается, так как в обоих случаях присваивается значение правого операнда... . Так где же тут указатель?

Если `a` это `int a[]`, то `int *array = a[0]` это ошибка.

--

Давайте я скажу про параметры "по значению" и "по адресу" немного по другому. 

Когда программисты говорят передача **"по значению"** это значит, что функция **не может изменить значение передаваемой ей переменной**. А **"по ссылке, указателю, адресу"** - что **может** (имеется в виду средствами языка).

Comment: @avp, да, там я уже напутал, забыл указатель убрать. Меня интересовал только сам факт, что передается значение во всех случаях, то есть когда в момент инициализация параметров значениями, которые вернули выражения и неважно кем эти выражения были, но а если обращать внимания на них, то да, как раз и всплывает передача по указателю или ссылке. Ладно, дальше нет смысла наверное продолжать, в принципе я понял то, что хотел, ещё перед созданием вопроса, но вот видимо не смог объяснить что именно.

Comment: @avp. фраза

    но ведь ссылка не позволяет выделить новую память под существующий объект

означает

    void f_value(int & a){
    a = new int; // ошибка
    }

    void f_pointer(int * a){
    a = new int; // нормально
    }

Answer (score 1):

пока читал вопрос несколько раз запустался :))

```
int foo(int a);//"a" это параметр функции

int foo(int a){//между "){" произойдёт присвоение a="значение из аргумента"
    return a+10;
}

int main(){
    int c=100,g;
    g=foo(c);// "c" это аргумент функции
             //тут выполнится такой порядок действий: 
             //временная_переменная="то что возвращает foo"
             //очистка того что занимала foo
             //g=временная_переменная
    return 0;
}
```

вот тут пример с ссылками [тык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/178009/c-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8).

Так что всё "передаётся по значению" но надо же как то отличать передачу указателя, ссылки и объекта, ведь если объект занимает 1гб то при передачи самого объекта  копироваться будет 1гб (того нужно 2 гб), а при передачи через указатель\ссылку нужно будет только пару байт. Потому такие передачи и называют по разному...

так что да **"некорректно задан вопрос"**!

Comment: Недавно я уже читал ваш ответ в том вопросе). Многое прояснило, а до этого тоже не совсем понимал что происходит. Кстати, вот этот тест http://www.quizful.net/question/kXP7PfGTMbcP . В комментариях как раз не хватает вашего [ответа][1], чтобы 

[1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/178009/c-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8#answer-container-180400

Comment: @strol ну это просто очередной холивар :) 

в принципе там  `romanik 02.11.2009 | 23:24:55` уже ответил... 

суть в том что **"стандарт"** это одно а **"устоявшийся сленг"** это другое.

создатель вопроса сделал его на основе сленга.

и хоть по стандарту это неправильно но на мой взгляд приемлемо.

Comment: Ну в принципе, да. Лучше просто знать эти оба варианта и если кто-то укажет на неправильность первого, то дополнить вторым вариантом. А ещё лучше не задавать такие вопросы или в какой-то более правильной форме делать их.

Answer (score 0):

Есть два способа, причем мы рассматриваем C++, а не си и не ассеблер( где можно говорить через стек или через регистры )

1. Передача по значению, где значение объекта копируется в стек или адресс объекта копируется в стек....
2. По ссылке, где в теле функции просто **непосредственно** обращаются к
   объекту, например сегменту данных, где была определега глобальная
   переменная, которая передается по ссылке. То есть, тут подменить
   адрес переданного объекта по ссылке нельзя в отличии от от передачи
   по указателю. Это просто как алиас объекта.

Comment: Тем не менее, ссылка - это переменная, содержащая адрес объекта. Чтобы использовать непосредственно адрес объекта, необходимо чтобы адрес объекта был известен на этапе компиляции. Тогда и передавать вообще ничего не нужно, просто из функции используем глобальный объект. И каждый раз один и тот же. А если все таки передаем ссылку в функцию как аргумент, то значит функция должна работать не только с одним-единственным объектом, а с разными объектами, то и адреса этих объектов она получает через переменную-ссылку, которая и позволяет при каждом вызове обрабатывать разные объекты.