# Как передать объект класса по ссылке?

Tags: c++

Весь вопрос в шапке, но продублирую: Как передать объект класса по ссылке?

Comment: void (objType& objectRef){/*...*/ }

Comment: Если Вы  «пытаетесь познать C++», то хотя бы книгу откройте по языку. Любую. Тогда таких вопросов появляться не будет.

Comment: Зря @ixSci читаете нравоучения. Q&A не для дискуссий и высоких материй. Вообще, сходу не нашел ответа на вопрос для Си++ в базе вопросов, так что сам по себе вопрос считаю адекватным, вот [первый ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/265803/8766), близкий по духу. Формулировка, вопроса конечно страдает, требуется правка. Лучше переформулируйте вопрос за автора, он просто не знает, что в нем написать. Думаю, против ни кто не будет.

Comment: Не понимаю, с чего вдруг Вы тут разводите цензуру. Не нравится вопрос - поднимайте тревогу, пусть модераторы решают. Совсем не обязательно дергать самолюбие авторов. Я вообще такие вопросы пропускаю мимо ушей. Этот привлек внимание как раз отрицательной оценкой.

Answer (score 3):

Передача объекта по ссылке используется достаточно часто и описана во многих книгах по С++, однако не всем получается быстро понять данный механизм.

Для начала рассмотрим принимающую сторону, т.е. функцию или метод класса, в который передается ссылка на объект. В простейшем случае это выглядит так:

```
void foo(ObjectType& object)
```

К типу передаваемого объекта добавляется символ `&`, причем его можно размещать как вплотную к типу, так и к имени объекта. Это зависит от стиля программирования.

При передачи объекта по ссылке не происходит копирования, т.е. мы по сути передаем адрес на объект, что быстрее и менее затратно по памяти. Плюс ко всему мы работаем непосредственно с объектом, переданным по ссылке. Если же объект исключительно входной и не должен быть изменен, то следует добавить модификатор const:

```
void foo(const ObjectType& object)
```

Теперь, изменить объект `object` в функции не получится. Чтобы было возможно вызывать методы класса `object` они должны быть объявлены как `const`.
Следует отметить, что есть понятие "ссылки на константу" а есть "константная ссылка". В данном случае мы имеем дело с первым понятием.

Теперь перейдем непосредственно к передаче объекта. Тут есть три варианта:

1. Локально.

   ```
   ObjectType myObject;
   foo(myObject);
   ```

   Просто передаем объект в функцию.
2. Указатель

   ```
   ObjectType* myObject = new ObjectType(...);
   foo(*myObject);`
   ```

   Тут несколько сложнее, т.к. мы создали указатель на объект. Указатель, по сути, адрес памяти. `*` перед ним является операцией разыменовывания, т.е. фактически передачей значения, как в первом случае.
3. Ссылка

   ```
   ObjectType& myObject = otherObject;
   foo(myObject);
   ```

   Ситуация аналогична первому варианту. Теперь мы имеем ссылку на объект и передаем ее в функцию.

А вообще стоит почитать литературу непосредственно по С++. Например Лафоре. Еще можно глянуть https://habrahabr.ru/post/251091/ и вообще на данную тему много написано. Гугл в помощь.