# Непредвиденный вызов деструктора string

Tags: c++, строки, visual-c++

Никак не могу справиться с проблемой в программе. Есть метод, который преобразует массив в строку. Он должен возвращать значение string, но когда программа доходит до строчки return s, она сначала вызывает деструктор, а только затем пытаясь вернуть пустое значение падает с ошибкой. Предполагаю, что ошибка может быть в модификаторах const, но не могу понять где именно.

```
string BigInt::toString() const{
string s = "";
char buf[BASE_DIG];
if (sign==-1)
{
    s = "-";
}
for(int k=coef.size()-1; k >= 0; k--)
{
    s += itoa(coef[k],buf,10);
}
return s;}
```

Код, где вызывается метод:

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const BigInt &i_value){
string str;
if(i_value.coef.empty())
{
    out<<0;
    return out;
}
str=i_value.toString();
out<<str;
return out;}
```

Comment: Странно. А что у вас за `string`? Это `std::string` или самописный класс?

Comment: std::string

Comment: У вас где-то ошибка в другом месте. Покажите ваш класс `BigInt`.

Comment: Я не знаю что такое BASE_DIG, но подозреваю, что стек может рушиться где-то при работе с buf...

Comment: @klopp: Думаю, это количество цифр в одном разряде BigInt'а, плюс 1, чтобы было куда записывать финальный `\0`. Если нет, в этой точке и вылетает :-)

Comment: VladD, вот это действительно помогло, спасибо! Я совершенно забыл про \o

Comment: @Xerocry: Я тоже много раз попадался, понимаю вас.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`string s`** создаётся в области видимости функции **`toString()`** это значит что когда **`toString()`** завершит работу будет очищен стек где хранится "**`s`**" для того чтобы это исправить выделяйте **`string s`** в heap'е (через new) и возвращайте указатель на "**`s`**" а не сам объект "**`s`**", в   **`operator<<()`** используйте указатель, а в строке **`out<<str;`** разыменуйте **`out<<(*str);`**

**upd**

в С++ объект удаляется при выходе из области видимости(если только сами не вызвали деструктор), вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/178009#180400) можешь почитать про то что и как передаётся и\или возвращается

**upd2**

после комментариев ниже я стал сомневаться что у вас проблема в string, так как  у std::string есть нормальный конструктор копирования. Возможно этот string это ваша собственная реализация и у неё не перегружен конструктор копирования.

в любом случае я предлагаю вам избавиться от **`itoa`** и использовать **`stringstream`** с его методом **`str()`** вот тут подробнее [habrahabr](http://habrahabr.ru/post/131977/), [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/), [ru.cppreference.](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream)

Comment: Подождите-подождите, что-то не то. Проверьте на простом примере:

    string test()
    {
        string s = "x";
        return s;
    }
    cout << test();

У `std::string` есть конструктор копирования, так что должно работать и без возврата объекта из кучи.

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat, разве у std::string нет конструктора копирования? В этой ситуации он должен отработать по определению:

    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    
    using namespace std;
    string aa()
    {
        string rc = "aa"; return rc;
    }
    int main()
    {
        string a = aa();
        cout << a; return 0;
    }

Ну и, конечно, мне таки непонятно: почему один раз не прошерстить код под отладчиком, чем гадать вслепую...

Comment: @VladD, @klopp да вы правы, там должен быть конструктор копирования! 

НО тогда резонный вопрос к @Xerocry почему это помогло?(действительно ли помогло?)

Comment: Нет, извините. Просто показалось. Просто проверял другое, и показалось, что всё заработало.

Comment: @Xerocry, ну так прогоните это место под отладчиком, вопрос решится куда быстрей. Для начала точку останова на BigInt::toString, и дальше - пошагово, с просмотром всех переменных.